# Progress bar for XGBoost and pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

Is there a way to implement a progress bar for training models with xgboost and pytorch?. 
if not, is there a way to estimate the training time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can reference the [tdqm](https://tqdm.github.io/)

Used like this:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10000)):
    ...
```

Comment: Use tqdm_notebook in colab

Comment: from tqdm import tqdm_notebook
for i in tqdm_notebook(range(10000)):
    ...

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using a python notebook, you can try this:

   ```
   import ipywidgets as widgets
   loading = widgets.IntProgress(value=0, min=0, max=100, step=1, description='Loading:')
   display(loading)

   for i in range(100):
       time.sleep(0.05)
       loading.value = i
   ```